# Google Analytics not working on custom Android ROM

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am developing an Android app for custom ROM which doesn't have Google play services in it.

I am trying to add google analytics but it is not working. I can't see any events in Google Analytics Dashboard.
I am 100% sure that there is no issue in the implementation of Google Analytics in the app.

Can anyone please help me how to use google analytics if you don't have play services on your device?

I also want to know which URL Google Analytics uses to send events to their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch#background

Basically you need the wakelock permission, and need to register the Google Analytics Service and BroadcastReceiver.